# Securing PDF Annotation

Tags: security, pdf, pdf-generation

We are working on an application which processes PDF documents. One of the features is adding annotations on the documents, and controlling the visibilty  of the annotations based on the user viewing the document.

Do the PDF specs support this?

EDIT:
This Is Desktop application which will have an embedded PDF viewer some metadata are stored remotely others are hidden in the document we need to make the application able to display specific information based on the user who Is using the App.

Comment: Is this a web application? What technology are you using to build your PDFs? I believe you can add annotations to a PDF - would you be doing this with an input PDF, or are you able to recreate the PDF from an input source (e.g. HTML)? However you cannot do user authentication with PDFs - you will need to do that elsewhere, and serve a different PDF. I think it would be best if you would edit your question, and add substantially more detail. (I will undownvote if you do).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the PDF with the annotation disabled by default. You can add Acrobat Javascript that prompts for a password, based on which the annotations can be displayed or kept hidden.

**UPDATE**: I didn't realize that the JS for this solution tries to save the annotation changes to the document. For this reason, it will not work in Adobe Reader. In Adobe Acrobat, the following code works.

```
var sResponse = app.response({cQuestion: "What's the secret password?", cTitle: "Secert Annotation", cLabel: "Password" });
this.syncAnnotScan(); 
if (sResponse == "one") { 
  var oAnnot = this.getAnnots()[0]; 
  if (oAnnot == null) { app.alert('not found'); } 
  else { oAnnot.noView =false; }
}
```

Adobe Lifecycle Extensions claim to provide this functionality to Adobe Reader. I have not used this software yet but you can give it a try.

Comment: Could you please provide us with the JavaScript code that demonstrates how to do this?